Facebook Developer Portal UseCases menu item missing for Facebook Test App
in the Facebook Developer Portal I created a new Facebook app, and enabled the Facebook Login as use-case.
Now from that Facebook app I created a clone so I also have a Facebook TEST app, where I could test some things for my test environment. Then I wanted to configure the same stuff for the Facebook TEST App as for the LIVE app, and I saw that only in the original App I have an extra menu button that says "Use-Cases" or so (in german: "Anwendungsfälle").
On the TEST app there is no such button. But I need that in order to get that app hooked up with my  Firebase test project. I don't know what I am doing wrong, and I'm about to simply create a completely NEW app (no clone as test) for this.
Did anyone have this issue?
And whenever I write Facebook, I really mean Meta...
I recreated the Facebook Test App as a clone from the LIVE one. Still no luck.

After a day or so of debugging, I think it is because for whatever reason I connected the TEST App to the Facebook Business Portfolio Account.
If I DON'T do that, I see all of the options in the menu.
Sorry for bothering you.
